# finding the geometric intersection point of three spheres

Tags: modeling

im new to blender so bear with me.

im a sculptor and mainly working with magnetic rods and steel ball nodes. in the blender worlds that means the geometric shape of my sculptures is the result of the length of all vertices in the mesh. if i change one rod the whole shape will readjust as the magnets can freely rotate around the balls.

here is what this looks like:

https://youtu.be/DkFMgQ94iac

so to model my magnetic scultpures in blender i need to construct every 3d point with 3 spheres that are the lengths of the connecting rods. i can only find meshed spheres which are not precise enough i think.

is there a function that finds a new point via the distances to three already existing points? how can this be done? i was also thinking about a rag doll model with bones and joints but this seems to be overkill.

thanks in advance.

---

yes, the tetrahedron is a math function but only works if all the vertices are the same length. i have two different lengths. 1 and 1.414. so there are many more shapes possible. i need the interesection of 3 radius, i think.

thast plain archimedean geometry. blender should have that included. maybe i should construct it in geogebra and import into blender?

ok so i just checked. yes geogebra has all these function in its 3dgeo section. but of course its missing the rag doll skeleton functions. which i need because i dont know the exact distances most of the time. all the angles at the nodes are a result of the whole mesh. so i need flexible joints.

maybe script the whole thing in python but that would be over my paygrade.

so here is a shape i just made to illustrate the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5NYD.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBL5H.jpg

its completely hollow and meshed and all the rods are either 1 or 1.414. i dont have a single coordinate, just the lengths and the mesh structure. how would you model that?

---

im surprised nobody seems to know what im talking about. here is a woodpecker i just made.

[image: specht]

see how the shape is defined by the geo of the mesh around it. thats a real world problem :-) only length 1 and 1.414 used. the resulting shape is always proportionally balanced because all the angles are around 90 to 60 deg and the faces have similar surface sizes.

a friend just sent me this link. i think the answer to my problem is in there.

https://www.rgb-labs.com/blender-190-simple-machines-1-part-2-rigging-bones/

Comment: Hello. You can use a equilateral triangle in 2d or a tetrahedron in 3d.